# REST Upload Excel file: POI library rejecting the file with Multipart Boundary

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest, apache-poi

I am trying to upload excel (.xlsx) file with AngularJS and REST (Jersey). The multipart boundary is getting added to the file received in REST which the apache POI Library rejects as invalid file with the following exception. What is the solution for this problem?

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:254)
    at com.bt.ngwfmt.framework.rest.FileUploadHandler.fileUpload(FileUploadHandler.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:203)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:673)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:274)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:254)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace 



    When I add @FormDataParam instead of @RequestParam I get the following   exception

    java.lang.NullPointerException
at   com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.unquoteMediaTypeParamete rs(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:245)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:172)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:158)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:85)
```

The inputstream with boundary is [image]

Java Snippet:

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadFile")

@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)

@NoCache
public String fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") InputStream inputStream) {

    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = null;

    XSSFSheet mySheet;

    try {
        myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream); //The exception is thrown at this line)
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Cant open workbook", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

.....

Angular snippet:

```
    angular.module(appName).controller('fileUploadController',
    [ '$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload) {

        $scope.uploadFile = function() {
            var file = $scope.myFile;
            console.log('file is ');
            console.dir(file);
            var uploadUrl = "myurl";
            fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };

    } ]);

angular.module(appName).directive('fileModel', [ '$parse', function($parse) {
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
} ]);

angular
    .module(appName)
    .service(
            'fileUpload',
            [
                    '$http',
                    function($http) {
                        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {
                            var fd = new FormData();
                            //
                            fd.append('file', file);
                            $http
                                    .post(
                                            uploadUrl,
                                            fd,
                                            {
                                                transformRequest :     angular.identity,
                                                headers : {
                                                    'Content-Type' : "multipart/form-data" //"multipart/form-data"
                                                }
                                            }).success(function() {
                                    }).error(function() {
                                    });
                        }
                    } ]);
```

The problem is similar to the one in the following link except that its specific to C#.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42620/uploading-excel-file-as-rest-post-certain-content-types-corrupted-when-saved

Comment: You should probably add your java code to your question

Comment: here is a link showing how to upload files using web services... hope it helps... http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-file-upload-example/

Comment: @RC. Hi, I have added all the details. This is my first question on stackoverflow, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The annotation should be `FormDataParam` instead of `RequestParam`. If you still getting the error, verify that you are receiving the file by writing it to temporary location. You usually get this error when the content of the file is blank which is more likely in your case.

Comment: I am getting the data after the boundary, you can see it in the image. I pasred the file in local and verified the data is same within the boundary.

Comment: In 'fileUpload' method, did you write the file to temporary location, and able to open it without errors? Regarding error with FormDataParam, which version of Jersey you are using?I See https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1658.

Comment: I am using the following Jersey jars.

jersey-bundle-1.19.jar
jersey-core-1.19.jar
jersey-multipart-1.19.jar